# should i use a Fragment or an Activity for an ever present View in my Android App?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

im developing an application with multiple screens using activities and fragments. The principle behind my decisions to use one or the other are based on the interaction in the application.

I have come to the conclusion that you should use an activity whenever major UI elements remain present after an event has occurred that forces the views inside the UI to change (An example of this can be a tabhost nested in the toolbar styled as the Google Play store android App with multiple fragments as childs. Another example is fragments representing the different rows or clickable elements on a navigation drawer).

So right now im presented with the dilemma of choosing once again between the two (fragment or activity) for a UI element that is going to be present across my whole application. Its triggered by a floating action button that launches a creation tool for an element inside my application and i needed to be accesible across all of my apps screens.

So to sum things up, what i need to know if its better to use a fragment or an activity for an element that is ever present across my whole application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use Fragments or a compound Views. But both in the right way.

Fragments are thought for reusable combinations of views. Compound Views are Layouts containing views. They are the right way if you want to create views from more primitive views, for example a View containing TextView and a increment- and decrement-button.

Fragments are more Activity-like. They have a real lifecycle. Your description   looks like you want to create acitivity-parts. And thats exactly what fragments do.

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an
>   Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to
>   build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities.

Taken from [Android SDK Documentation: Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Comment: Thank you! i think i have a better idea of what im about to do! if i reach to any new conclusion ill be sure to post it here!